# Are there standard definitions for the terms alpha, beta and RC1 in software development?

Tags: release-management

I am interested to know if the terms alpha, beta and RC1 are terms that are used
throughout the software industry or just MS.

What are the definitions?

Malcolm

Answer (score 3):

Yes these are standard terms and have standard definitions, though they are often stretched a little in this Web 2.0 world...

Wikipedia has a good explanation of all the terms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_stage#Alpha

Answer (score 1):

Yes these are terms that are in general use.  Alpha versions are generally for internal use.  Beta versions are typically given to selected customers who can use the software, recognizing that it not yet ready for release, and give feedback on problems.  Typically, these will be more sophisticated customers who are able to help find problems with the software.  Release candidates are generally the versions that one thinks are ready to ship.  These may contain small errors, but the basic idea is that this version will ship absent any  major flaws found at the last minute.

I don't think that there are any formal definitions and the usage may differ from company to company and product to product.  For instance, many Google offerings seem to exist in perpetual beta.

Answer (score 1):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle

Here is the concise and general definition for Alpha and Beta Releases:

The alpha release is characterized by:

A1. It is the first phase to begin software testing.

A2. Developers test the software using white box techniques (sometimes called Pre-Alpha).

A3. Additional validation is then performed using black box or gray box techniques, by another testing team. Moving to black box testing inside the organization is known as alpha release.

A4. Alpha software can be unstable and could cause crashes or data loss.

A5  It is usually not available externally (except by special arrangements and needs, or for open source software).

A6. It usually ends with a feature freeze, (called Feature Complete status).

Beta Release is characterized by:

B1. It follows alpha release i.e. begins after Feature Complete status.

B2. SW will generally have less bugs than Alpha, but more bugs than completed software, as well as speed/performance issues. It may still cause crashes or data loss.

B3. The focus of beta testing is reducing impacts to users, often incorporating usability testing.

B4.  It is typically the first time that the software is available outside of the organization that developed it (for proprietary SW).

Answer (score -1):

There is only one standard definition I've ever encountered that adequately covers all uses of these terms:

- Alpha software is software which the originator has labeled "alpha".
- Beta software is software which the originator has labeled "beta".
- Gamma software is software which the originator has labeled "gamma".  (Rarely used anymore.)
- RC  software is software which the originator has labeled "RC ".

No other "standard" definition comes close to this one in accuracy and applicability.